# Отсутствующие шрифты

Tags: вёрстка, photoshop, psd

Что делать, если при открытии макета psd в Photoshop, сообщает что некоторые шрифты отсутствуют на компьютере, предлагает обработать с помощью Typekit? Ведь для верстки нужно получить не только графику, но и шрифты.

Comment: *для верстки нужно получить не только графику, но и шрифты.* Ну так и получайте... вместе с макетом.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас в системе эти шрифты не установлены, то Фотошоп их и не увидит. Однако, если Вы откроете макет, выберите слой с отсутствующим шрифтом, затем выберите инструмент "Текст". На Панели инструментов Вы сможете увидеть название шрифта (хоть его и нет в Вашей системе), заключенное в квадратные скобки. Далее, скачайте требуемые шрифт из Интернета и установите себе в систему. Далее, закройте и откройте макет в Фотошопе.